# How to insert pictures without hard coded dimensions?

Tags: images, responsive

How can I insert pictures into a post without any hard coded dimensions (e.g. `<img src="" alt="" />` instead of `<img src="" alt="" width="" height="" />`)? I don't want my users to switch to the HTML tab and remove the parameters by themselves, so I was wondering if there is any filter I can use to achieve this?

Note: I'm already inserting them in "Full size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the meantime: `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the `src` for the images. I think it ends up by being the easiest solution and it requires no filters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it works for me.

In the functions.php of the theme you are using, put this:

```
function remove_img_src($html)
{
    $html = preg_replace('@(width|height)="([0-9])+" ?@i', '', $html);

    return $html;
}

add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'remove_img_src', 10, 8);
```

It uses regular expresions to change the output that is inserted in the editor.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when pulling the images from the post gallery, using [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image). Any suggestions?

Comment: For what i see on the code, it seems that it can't be done without hardcode the changes. There's a filter in line [663](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/media.php#L663), but on line [665](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/media.php#L665) is harcoded the $hwstring wich contains that width/height definition.

Comment: Any more ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do it with image captions, but not images at present:

From the wp-hackers mailing list:

> I've got a filter I use that forces captions to be responsive on the
>   frontend. Definitely cuts down on the headaches.
>
> Gist here: https://gist.github.com/2243601
>
> Drew

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I've used `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the `src` for the images. I think it ends up by being the most easy solution and it requires no filters.